# How do I manage a lot of cloudformation template/stacks on aws?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, devops

I have about 5 cloudformation templates and I am wondering how I can manage them in such a way there will be a master template that can import the resources from the 5 templates and also add conditions that could stop some parameters from being installed when they are not needed.

Comment: you can import templates stored in s3 by using [include transform](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/create-reusable-transform-function-snippets-and-add-to-your-template-with-aws-include-transform.html). You can disable parts of template by using [conditions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/conditions-section-structure.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of Cloudformation [nested stacks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-nested-stacks.html), and conditionally deploy child stacks in your master stack.

Based on the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-nested-stacks.html):

> Using nested stacks to declare common components is considered a best practice.

I'd recommend reading through those [best practices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html#nested) to make sure this is the best choice for your situation